# Hex to base-64 and other bases

Tags: python

I have some string representing a number in hex and I want to convert it to base-64. How do I do this and how does this suggestion work? As I need to have an understanding of how it works.

The first thing I thought of was (I'm a noob) implementing a simple algorithm that would proceed as one would when working with pen and paper, though I imagine Python has this sort of stuff "built-in".

I can implement this through searching on the internet however I need an understanding of how it works.

Some sample questions to give you an idea of the explanations I need:

- If your answer requires strings of the type `b'...'` could you please explain what they are and why does `b64encode()` seems to only accept objects of this type as arguments?
- Why does `int()` only work up to base-36 and how can I in general handle conversion between different bases tidily and could you give a further explanation if your solution involves this function?

So if anyone could give me some pointers here. I am not being able to extract much from the documentation as this type of knowledge seems to be already expected.

Thanks.

Comment: As a quick guess the base 36 issue may just be encoding (26 letters and 10 numerals to encode is all you have to output using `10=A`)

Comment: Are there any other functions such as int() that I can use to convert between bases >36 as succinctly?

Comment: With regards to your question about strings of the form `b"hi scarlett"` see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: You're asking many different questions in one Stack Overflow question. Please keep it limited to one question per question.

Comment: *what's with the `b'...'`'". Those are [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html?#pep-3112-byte-literals)

Comment: @Colonel kind of. I wasn't really looking for answers to those many questions particularly, the purpose of mentioning them was rather to serve as an example of the type of question that I had, and I was hoping that someone could show me the way to somewhere I could learn about those. Anyway, I'm sorry, I wasn't really sure how to phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that walks you trough the process of converting from a hex string to a b64 encoded string.

```
import base64
x=int('0xABCDEF01',base=16)
print("x  : ",x)
b=x.to_bytes(length=4,byteorder='big')
print("b  : ",b)
e=base64.b64encode(b)
print("e  : ",e)
b2=base64.b64decode(e)
print("b2 : ",int(b2.hex(),base=16))
```

Output:

```
x  :  2882400001
b  :  b'\xab\xcd\xef\x01'
e  :  b'q83vAQ=='
b2 :  2882400001
```

Some (lengthy) explanations: so we start with a hex in a string, nothing special, `int` takes it along with the base to turn it into a regular integer `x`. To python `x` is a bunch of bits representing a number that will be printed in base 10 most of the time. We can ask the bit representation using `x.to_bytes`. The result is a sequence of bytes that will print as `b'...'` note that the printing process automatically tries to convert the bytes to ascii caracters or to somthing like`\xab` if that given byte isn't associated with a ascii character. So we then feed the bytes to `b64encode` that is usually use to process files hence that byte-object requirement and it spits an *ascii-string* as a byte object. With that result the reverse process is similar :  b64 *ascii-string* -> binary number in bytes -> hex -> int.

Comment: `b64encode` returns an ASCII-string? So, for instance the first `q` in `e` is a byte holding the value 113? For the computer, that string is a different number than the one it happens to represent for us (a number in base-64)?

Comment: Base64 orignal purpose is to take raw bytes of data (that may not be printable as ascii) and turn it to an ascii sequence that can be copy/pasted in a text message, to give an example. So **the real/expected output of b64 is the sequence of characters you can read**. But as you have noted, for the computer (and for python) those characters are just a sequence of bytes; to make python understand that they are indeed a string of ascii-characters you would have to call `e.decode("ascii")`.

Answer (score 1):

assume input of 'aaccffdde5e5ff'

```
import binascii,base64
input_str = 'aaccffdde5e5ff'
dehexed_str = binascii.unhexlify(input_str)
base64_str = base64.b64encode(dehexed_str)
```

`b'...'` is just a bytestring you can encode a normal unicode string to bytes with

`as_bytes = u'hello world'.encode('utf-8')`

to handle arbitrary base conversion to base10 see this tutorial

http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/tobase10.htm

here is a function to convert any string in any alphabet to decimal base 10

```
def int10(s,alphabet):
    base = len(alphabet)
    return sum([alphabet.index(c)*base**i for i,c in enumerate(s[::-1])])

hexAlphabet="0123456789abcdef"
print(int10('f3',hexAlphabet))
```